# How do you use a shapefile asset as your AOI in GEE?

Tags: javascript, assets, google-earth-engine

I've uploaded a zip file of shapefiles as an asset to Google Earth Engine. How do I make this as my AOI? I've tried adding in the AOI as coordinates and ee.Geometry.Polygon but it doesn't cover the entire AOI that I need, whereas my shapefiles do. But I'm unsure how to implement these shapefiles into my code, so it shows up. This is the first part of my code. I'm extremely new to this, any help would be appreciated! :)

[image]

```
var startDate = ee.Date('2018-12-01'); //2018-12-31'); GEE: 2017-03-28T00:00:00  ???
var endDate = ee.Date('2020-09-01'); //'2021-06-01'
var days = 45;
var cloud_shadow_percentage = 50; // (max)
var cloud_cover_percentage = 50;  // (max)

// note: Sentinel-2-SR from 2017-03-28 but TOA from 2015-06-23
// -----------------------------------------------------
//Map.addLayer(AOI, {}, 'AOI', true);  
Map.centerObject(AOI, 13);

var imageStartDate1 = startDate.advance(-days,"day");
var imageStartDate2 = startDate.advance(days,"day");
var imageEndDate1   = endDate.advance(-days,"day");
var imageEndDate2   = endDate.advance(days,"day");

//S2-SR: COPERNICUS/S2_SR //LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR");

var imagery = ee.ImageCollection(S2)
    //.filterDate(imageEndDate1, imageEndDate2)
    .filterBounds(AOI)
    //.filterMetadata('CLOUD_SHADOW_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', cloud_shadow_percentage)
    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT', 'less_than', cloud_cover_percentage)
    ;

var Sen2_collection = ee.ImageCollection(imagery)
    .filterDate(imageStartDate1, imageStartDate2)
    .filterBounds(AOI);

var Sen2_ = ee.ImageCollection(Sen2_collection)
    .sort('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT').first();  

var Sen2 =  ee.Image(Sen2_)
  .clip(AOI);

var Sen2end_collection = ee.ImageCollection(imagery)
    .filterDate(imageEndDate1, imageEndDate2)
    .filterBounds(AOI);

var Sen2end_ = ee.ImageCollection(Sen2end_collection)
    .sort('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT').first(); 

var Sen2end =  ee.Image(Sen2end_)
  .clip(AOI);

Map.addLayer(Sen2, {bands:['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min:0, max:5000}, 'rgb start', false);   
Map.addLayer(Sen2end, {bands:['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min:0, max:5000}, 'rgb end', false);

print("Sen2_collection", Sen2_collection);
print("Sen2end_collection", Sen2end_collection);
print("Sen2", Sen2);
print("Sen2end", Sen2end);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update ---

Hi! I found a code to make it work. Hope this may help somebody else :)

```
//Display the shapefile into the interactive map
Map.addLayer(AOI);
//Display the view to the center of the screen and scale the view
Map.centerObject(AOI,13);
//Define styling and determine the color of the shapefile 
var styling = {color: 'red', fillColor: '00000000'};
Map.addLayer(AOI.style(styling));
```

https://sryhandiniputeri.medium.com/input-a-shapefile-in-google-earth-engine-d358ced1d095

Rename the 'AOI' section to whatever your 'var ___' import is called.

Answer (score 0):

Your [GEE](https://code.earthengine.google.com/999ed3a047a5c153406afb1120bb786c) code works fine, I just used the AOI as a polygon/shapefile, which I have as an asset.

The issue would probably be with the shapefile you are using,

1. It may be because the shapefile may have a large number of polygons/multipolygon
2. If the shapefile is having so many details/curves/edges, the JSON requested to the Server sometimes exceeds the limit and GEE gives an error. (If this is the case, then you need to smooth the boundary of your shapefile.)